# Filtering Files based on Dates

Tags: python, excel

I have bunch of files named FXRATES_DD-MM-YYY.xlsx  residing in a folder.How can I filter out and read only certain files based on specific date range?

Comment: Loop through the files and read only those, who are in this specific date range. Both `Python` and `Excel` can do it easily.

Comment: What part of this process do you not know how to do? What have you tried? Does it really matter that the files are Excel files?

Comment: I was able to read all the files first,concantenate them and then filter based on column values(Data is one of the column value as well) using df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, glob.glob(os.path.join('', "FX*.xlsx"))))  But in real world I am facing problems as size of all these files are huge.Hence I intend to read and concatenate only those files within the date range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started, assuming all of your filenames are formatted similarly:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime
import os, re

#Enter date range
dates = []
d1 = date(2017, 11, 5)  #start date
d2 = date(2017, 11, 19)  #end date

for i in range((d2-d1).days + 1):
    d = d1 + timedelta(days=i) #Establish date range
    dates.append(datetime.strptime(str(d), '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d-%#m-%Y'))

os.chdir('Enter file location here')

for i in os.listdir(): #For each file in the directory you specify
    file_date.append(re.findall(r'FXRATES_(.*)\.xlsx', i)[0])
```

The list file_date should include all of the files that fall within the date range.